# How to concatenate CComBSTR and strings?

Tags: c++, string

How to concatenate `CComBSTR` and strings?

I've tried this way :

```
CComBSTR a = "DEF";
CComBSTR strRequete = "ABC'" + a + "GHI"; //marked line
```

But I'm getting an error on `a` of the `marked line` telling :

> Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate, you have [8 methods](http://www.369o.com/data/books/atl/0321159624/ch02lev1sec3.html):

```
HRESULT Append(LPCOLESTR lpsz, int nLen);             
HRESULT Append(LPCOLESTR lpsz);                       
HRESULT Append(LPCSTR);                               
HRESULT Append(char ch);                              
HRESULT Append(wchar_t ch);                           

HRESULT Append(const CComBSTR& bstrSrc);          
CComBSTR& operator+=(const CComBSTR& bstrSrc);

HRESULT AppendBSTR(BSTR p);
```

Using the += operator, you can append like this:

```
CComBSTR strSentence = OLESTR("Now is the time ");

// strSentence contains "Now is the time "
CComBSTR str11 (OLESTR("for all good men ");
// calls Append(const CComBSTR& bstrSrc);
strSentence.Append(str11);
// strSentence contains "Now is the time for all good men "
// calls Append(LPCOLESTR lpsz);
strSentence.Append((OLESTR("to come "));
// strSentence contains "Now is the time for all good men to come "
// calls Append(LPCSTR lpsz);
strSentence.Append("to the aid ");
// strSentence contains
// "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid "

CComBSTR str12 (OLESTR("of their country"));
strSentence += str12; // calls operator+=()
// "Now is the time for all good men to come to
// the aid of their country"
```

More information like this at this link: http://www.369o.com/data/books/atl/0321159624/ch02lev1sec3.html

Comment: which is the best practise?

Comment: @Luciekulza: You have 6 overloaded `Append` methods that take in different types. One version that requires a `CComBSTR`. So if you want to append with the `+` sign, then use the latter. There isn't a best practice in this case. `Append` is more verbose to me, could look better.

Comment: Would you please provide a short example like FredrickGauss's did?

Comment: @Luciekulza: The examples are in the second block. Take a look at the last `+=`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, one more question please : to convert CComBSTR to SQLWCHAR*, do I need to simply `(SQLWCHAR*)strSentence` ?

Comment: @Luciekulza: That's a different question. Feel free to post another one.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says:

The `CComBSTR` class is a wrapper for `BSTR`s, which are length-prefixed strings.

Either you have to use [CComBSTR::Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yd4hs8c.aspx)
or

> bstr = CStringW(L"String2") + bstr

[Refer to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdyd6xz6.aspx).